# Is it possible to use the same k-folds in cross_val_predict that are in cross_val_score?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, classification

Hi if we do the following to calculate cross validated accuracy:

```
cv_acc = cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, cv=5, scoring='accuracy')
```

Is it possible to estimate the y predictions and create a confusion matrix (as below) using the same inputs to the k-folds in `cross_val_score`?

```
y_pred = cross_val_predict(model, X_train, y_train, cv=5)
conf_mat = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
```

Is there a way to store how the k-folds are exactly split in `cross_val_score` to ensure a comparable confusion matrix?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_score, cross_val_predict
k_folds = KFold(n_splits=5)
splits = list(k_folds.split(X_train, y_train)) # note list here as k_folds.split is a one-off generator
cv_acc = cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, cv=splits, scoring='accuracy')
y_pred = cross_val_predict(model, X_train, y_train, cv=splits)
```

See docs for [cross_val_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html) and [cross_val_predict](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html) for more.

A full working example:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_score, cross_val_predict
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

k_folds = KFold(n_splits=5)
X_train, y_train = make_classification(1000)
splits = list(k_folds.split(X_train, y_train))
model = LogisticRegression()
cv_acc = cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, cv=splits, scoring='accuracy')
y_pred = cross_val_predict(model, X_train, y_train, cv=splits)
```

Comment: Thanks mate!! Great help :)